# Drupal Commerce input price formatting

Tags: 7, commerce

Presenting price with comma separator is working. But while editing product (or creating) I have to use price with dot separation, otherwise I'm getting warning, that field doesn't contain value. So right now I have to remember to use dot and after I see common - it's annoying. Does anyone deal with this with success?

I want to enter 24,43 as value, but it is not recognizable as value (which actually is).

Instead I have to enter 24.43, which is not accessible from num pad with current regional settings.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is what you look for - currently it has a patch that needs work.
http://drupal.org/node/1450736